# Why won't this compile? I've tried several things. Errors are reported in the .h files and I've tried several different groups of INCLUDE files

Tags: windows

I want to run a windows command or program from a C++ program.
This one line program will not compile, stops in .h files.
I've tried several groups of .h files.

```
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>

main (void)

{
system ("dir c:");
}
```

Comment: _This one line program_ …?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED !!!
The Source file was .cpp
Saved it as .c reloaded it, and all compiled and ran OK!
The original intent as to be able to call another program. Here is the result.

//No includes

main ()

{

system ("notepad");

return(0);

}

//Save as a .c file to compile.